# Extract strings from nested array in Perl

Tags: programming-challenge, regex, perl

Extract the strings from nested arrays in Perl.

It prints: `a, b, c, d, E`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say signatures current_sub); 
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

my $nested = [1, 'a', [2, 3, 'b'], [4, [5, 6, 7, ['c']], [7, [8, 9, [10, 'd']]], 11, 'E']];

print join ', ', @{ extract_strings($nested) };

sub extract_strings($input) {
    my @output = ();

    my $loop = sub ($val) {
        if (ref $val eq 'ARRAY') {
            __SUB__->($_) for @{ $val };
        } else {
            push(@output, $val) if $val =~ /^[a-zA-Z]/;
        }
    };

    $loop->($input);

    return \@output;
}
```

Any idea for improvement without not core dependencies?

Comment: Looks fine to me :) The name of the sub, `flatten` might be improved to `extract_strings`?  If wanted, speed could be improved by using `Inline::C` or XS.

Comment: It is exactly extract_strings in my edit :)

Comment: Actually, there is something that might be a bug: `push(@output, $val) if /^[a-zA-Z]/;` vs `push(@output, $val) if $val =~ /^[a-zA-Z]/;` I don't understand why this actually work. What is `$_` in the `else`? I'll edit the function.

Comment: It is not allowed to modify the code when answers have been posted. It can invalidate them. I have rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your concept of "string" seems incomplete.  I would look to firm up that definition and precisely match the need.  Is `""` a string?  Do you want "valid identifiers" (`/^[^\d\W]\w+$/`) or "plausible ASCII words"  (`/^[A-Za-z]+$/`) or just "not numbers"  (`!/ ^ ( [+-]? \d* \.? \d+ (?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)? ) $/x`)?

I like `use warnings FATAL => 'all';` so that I don't miss a warning in the midst of other output.

A fat arrow between arguments of different purpose can enhance readability.

Coding in functional style (with `grep` and `map` instead of `@output`) is a natural fit to this kind of problem.

Plain old recursion is suited to the task and would obviate the need for experimental features.

Having `extract_strings` take a ref (as it does now) and return a list simplifies the logic even further.

```
print join ', ' => extract_strings($nested);

sub extract_strings {
    grep /^[a-zA-Z]/ => map { ref eq 'ARRAY' ? extract_strings($_) : $_ } @{ $_[0] } 
}
```

If returning a ref is necessary, wrap and unwrap accordingly:

```
sub extract_strings {
    [ grep /^[a-zA-Z]/ => map { ref eq 'ARRAY' ? @{ extract_strings($_) } : $_ } @{ $_[0] } ]
}
```